# AutoCompleteExtender Causes Postback when scrolling

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, autocompleteextender

Only on IE, the textbox postback is triggered when the user scrolls the autocomplete results. I have no problems in Chrome or FF.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBreakfast" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="headerinput" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtBreakfast_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox> 

<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtBreakfast_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" ContextKey="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="/service/service1.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetFoodNames" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtBreakfast" CompletionInterval="500"  CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem" DelimiterCharacters=";,:" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

How it's supposed to work:
User starts typing food, then selects the food from the extender div, then a postback occures and it causes additional database information to be displayed based on the food.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just used jquery ui, I found no solution to having a postback on an autocomplete, it just doesn't work in IE.

I read up on it online, and that's the conclusion

Answer (score 0):

if you remove

```
AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtBreakfast_TextChanged"
```

it works?

after the textbox text is changed(you select a value from the dropdown list) the event OnTextChanged is triggered..

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `AutoPostBack="true"` and do the PostBack manually. Add a JavaScript function to do the PostBack, and add `OnClientItemSelected` to the AutoCompleteExtender to use it.

```
function BreakfastChanged() {
    __doPostBack("txtBreakfast", "");
}

<asp:TextBox 
    ID="txtBreakfast" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    CssClass="headerinput" 
    runat="server" 
    OnTextChanged="txtBreakfast_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox> 

<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    ID="txtBreakfast_AutoCompleteExtender" 
    runat="server" 
    UseContextKey="true" 
    ContextKey="" 
    Enabled="True" 
    ServicePath="/service/service1.asmx" 
    ServiceMethod="GetFoodNames" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    CompletionSetCount="10" 
    TargetControlID="txtBreakfast" 
    CompletionInterval="500"  
    CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
    CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem" 
    DelimiterCharacters=";,:" 
    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true"
    OnClientItemSelected="BreakfastChanged">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```